# Run looping python script in ubuntu as a service

Tags: python, linux, service, sleep

Short:
I have a python script that I would like to install as a service. It does, however, terminate when run as a service, which it does not when run manually as root.

Full:
I have a physical HD44780 LCD display attatched to a server displaying various diagnostics.
The data is collected by a python script, that needs to be run with python2 and have root privileges. 
The script is essentially a loop that collects info, calculates some values and writes to the LCD. Hereafter it goes back to sleep for 5 secs, and does it again.

I would like to run this as a service and have followed this tutorial:
[Run python script at startup with Systemd service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/84892/run-python-script-at-startup-with-systemd-service)

My Python script is placed in **/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py** and is something like this:

```
def runCycle():
   calculate values....
   time.sleep(5) <--line 121
   print on lcd

while True:
  runCycle() <-- line 170
```

Servicefile is placed in **/etc/systemd/system/lcdsysinfo.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Service running system info LCD
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/lcdsysinfo.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python2 "/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py >>/var/log/lcdsysinfo.log 2>&1"
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and I have a writeable textfile at **/var/log/lcdsysinfo.log**

After doing this, I ran

```
sudo systemctl enable lcdsysinfo
sudo systemctl start lcdsysinfo
```

Nothing happens on the display, and if I look at

```
systemctl status lcdsysinfo
```

I will get

```
lcdsysinfo.service - Service running system info LCD
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/lcdsysinfo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-01-05 16:04:17 CET; 9min ago
Main PID: 6469 (code=exited, status=2)

Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: lcdsysinfo.service: Service hold-off time over, 
scheduling restart.
Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: lcdsysinfo.service: Scheduled restart job, restart 
counter is at 5.
Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: Stopped Service running system info LCD.
Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: lcdsysinfo.service: Start request repeated too 
quickly.
Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: lcdsysinfo.service: Failed with result 'exit- 
code'.
Jan 05 16:04:17 bo-stationary systemd[1]: Failed to start Service running system info LCD.
```

If I cat the logfile at **/var/log/lcdsysinfo.log**, I get

```
/usr/bin/python2: can't open file '/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py", line 170, in <module> runCycle()
File "/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py", line 121, in runCycle
time.sleep(sleepIntervalSecs)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What am I doing wrong?

It seems to me that is something to do with putting the loop to sleep, but I have some calculations that are done over time, so I would really use the python loop and keep stats in memory, than reading and saving to files to keep state and call script in a cronlike fashion.

Comment: the logfile is showing `can't open file '/etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py'`, did you give the proper permissions to this script using `chmod`?

Comment: logfile permissions was -rwx------, have changed it to -rwxrwxrwx.
Result is that the service still is stopped and has the same status, but now the logfile is empty.

I can perfectly fine run the script with **sudo /usr/bin/python2 /etc/opt/lcdsysinfo.py >>/var/log/lcdsysinfo.log 2>&1**